# How to create a histogram for the number of times certain words appear in a column?

Tags: r

So in my data frame I have a column like this with the name of different species, several of them repeated many times:

```
     species        
---------------------
Gadus morhua 
Tilapia guineensis  
Tilapia zillii      
Fundulus rubrifrons 
Eutrigla gurnardus  
Sprattus sprattus   
Gadus morhua        
Tilapia zillii      
Gadus morhua
```

What I want is a bar plot where the x axis is the name of each species, and the y axis is the number of times that each species appears on my data frame.
Thanks you so much for any answers

Comment: Looks like you need `?table`

Comment: You probably mean a bar chart, not a histogram. A histogram is to show the distribution of a continuous variable. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `count()` function from the tidyverse package to count the number of occurrences. From there you can plot it with `ggplot2`. If you have lots of species you might not want to show them all, but the [R Graphics Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316956) should have instructions for that.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <-
  tribble(~species,
"Gadus morhua",
"Tilapia guineensis", 
"Tilapia zillii",   
"Fundulus rubrifrons",
"Eutrigla gurnardus", 
"Sprattus sprattus",  
"Gadus morhua",   
"Tilapia zillii",    
"Gadus morhua")

counted_data <- count(data,species)

print(counted_data)

ggplot(counted_data, aes(x=species,y=n))+geom_col()
```

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  species                 n
  <chr>               <int>
1 Eutrigla gurnardus      1
2 Fundulus rubrifrons     1
3 Gadus morhua            3
4 Sprattus sprattus       1
5 Tilapia guineensis      1
6 Tilapia zillii          2
```

[image: resulting plot]